# Massive CPU usage when using Xcode3 and iPhone is on the same network

Tags: iphone, xcode, cpu, wireless, debug-symbols

Xcode4 comes with good intentions, but it can't beat Xcode3 in terms of agility. I find myself going back to Xcode3 every now and then, but there's one issue that makes this almost impossible. Whenever I have my iPhone around, Xcode3 tries to connect to it wirelessly, consuming insane amounts of CPU (stalling the whole computer in a matter of minutes). The only solution I've found so far is to get the iPhone in airplane mode.

Does anyone know how to disable this wireless communication entirely so that I can use Xcode3 normally?

Answer (score 1):

I installed [TCPBlock(donationware)](http://tcpblock.wordpress.com/) and blocked all traffic by usbmuxd an so far have no more problems using Xcode 3.

1. Install TCPBlock
2. Start xcode and wait for usbmuxd to appear in the "connecting apps" tab and add it to
3. the blocked list
4. Work with Xcode3 without problems.
5. disable TCPBlock after work if you need usbmuxd

Comment: martin, im suprised i haven't been able to find more on this. the same thing is happening to me. ipv6 connection running on process usbmuxd. i do not ever remember initializing any such connection, and would love any more information you have about it. i have another solution to the problem as well if you're interested. let me know - that goes for anyone.